# Find duplicates by one of multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have divs with multiple classes (brand and color) like:

```
<div id="pad">
    <div class="bmw white"> </div>
    <div class="porsche yellow"> </div> 
    <div class="porsche red"> </div> 
    <div class="bmw white"> </div> 
    <div class="bmw blue"> </div> 
    <div class="bmw white"> </div> 
</div>

<div id="same"></div>
```

And when I need to know how many duplicate brands I have in **#pad** I use this code:

```
function sameCars() {
    var elems = $("#pad div").length;
    var brands = ['bmw', 'porsche'];
    for (var i=0; i<brands.length; i++) {
        var k = 0;
        for (var j=0; j<elems; j++) {
            var mainDiv = document.getElementById('pad'),
                childDiv = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('div')[j];
            if(childDiv.className.split(' ')[0] == brands[i]) {
                k = k+1;
            }
        }
        addiv = document.getElementById("same");
        addiv.innerHTML += brands[i] + ": " + k;
    }
}
```

Now I want to make changes in my code:

1) to find duplicates for all classes (there could be more classes, first one is brand, the second one is color, etc) like **bmw: 4, porsche: 2, white: 3, black: 3, sedan: 2, coupe: 3**

2) not to use list of brands, colors, etc. I don't want to make a long list of all possible colors or car brands. Just get colors from classname

3) Make my code shorter and more elegant

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: 1) and 2). 3) is not necessary

Comment: you want to get rid of creating array for such cars?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to dynamically gather all classes fists:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var duplicates = {};
  var $pad = $('#pad');

  $('#pad > div').each(function () {
    var classes = $(this)[0].classList;

    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
      if (typeof duplicates[classes[i]] === 'undefined') {
        duplicates[classes[i]] = 1;
      } else {
        duplicates[classes[i]]++;
      }
    }
  });
  
  for (var j in duplicates) {
    $pad.append('<div>'+j+':'+duplicates[j]+'</div>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pad">
    <div class="bmw white"> </div>
    <div class="porsche yellow"> </div> 
    <div class="porsche red"> </div> 
    <div class="bmw white"> </div> 
    <div class="bmw blue"> </div> 
    <div class="bmw white"> </div> 
</div>

<div id="same"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get classes dynamically and apply logic to get unique counts like this.

```js
sameCars();
function sameCars() {
    var brands = [];
    var colors = [];
    $("#pad div").each(function(){
      brands.push($(this).attr("class").split(' ')[0])
      colors.push($(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1])
    });
    //console.log(brands)
    //console.log(colors)
    var cars_count = {};
    $.each(brands, function( index, value ) {
      cars_count[value] = cars_count[value] + 1 || 1;
    });
    console.log("Unique cars count :")
    console.log(cars_count);
    
    var count_color = {};
    $.each(colors, function( index, value ) {
      count_color[value] = count_color[value] + 1 || 1;
    });
    console.log("Unique Colors count :")
    console.log(count_color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pad">
    <div class="bmw white"> </div>
    <div class="porsche yellow"> </div> 
    <div class="porsche red"> </div> 
    <div class="bmw white"> </div> 
    <div class="bmw blue"> </div> 
    <div class="bmw white"> </div> 
</div>

<div id="same"></div>
```

Comment: Same assumptions as from Eduardo answer: your classes must be always in same order and creating new group of classes will require your code modification.

Comment: That's correct! but as per the HTML structure, we even can't assume which is car name and which is a color name.He should use some HTML attribute like data-car-name, data-color-name in his dom elements.

Comment: Why? It has different color, that's all what is needed to have distinct classes.

Comment: @Justinas i think what Mayank means is that he could need to show the unique colors list and the unique car list separately, with your requirement of being able to have the classes randomly sorted, you would not be able to separate the list of colors and the list of brands (which was my intention in my first suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice way of getting what you want. **Note** I do not manipulate the DOM, I'll leave that up to you.

```
function classIsDup(className, setOfClasses)
{
    return (setOfClasses.indexOf(className) > -1);
}

function getDuplicates()
{
    var setOfClasses = [];
    var listOfDuplicates = [];
    $('#pad').children('div').each(function( index ) {

        if(classIsDup($(this).attr('class'), setOfClasses))
        {
            listOfDuplicates.push($(this).attr('class'));
        }
        else
        {
            setOfClasses.push($(this).attr('class'));
        }
    });
    // just in case dups exist within the list of dups
    $.uniqueSort(listOfDuplicates);
}

getDuplicates();
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript example (no jquery required)

```
var parentWrapper = document.getElementById('pad');
var displayWrapper = document.getElementById('same');
var classesList = getUniqueClassList(parentWrapper);
displayCounts(classesList);

function displayCounts(list) {
  for (var className in list) {
    var number = list[className];
    displayWrapper.innerHTML += className + ' ' + number + '<br>';
  }
}

function getUniqueClassList(wrapper) {
  var list = {};
  for (var elem of wrapper.getElementsByTagName('div')) {
    for (var cssClass of elem.classList) {
        if (!list[cssClass]) {
                list[cssClass] = 1;
      } else {
        list[cssClass]++;
      }
    }
  }
  return list;
}
```

Fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/r1rk1xL3/5/

Comment: What you have more then 2 types of classes? What if you have `white bmw` and `bmw red`, or even better `big white bmw` and `white bmw 4-door`?

Comment: @Justinas the method getUniqueClassList gets as a second argument the position of the desired class, since as you say you might want to have a third class for another property you can just pass the right index of the target class.Obviously since you want to get dynamically the list of brands, colors you need to set the classes in the same order always.

Comment: It's not always possible to have same order for classes, also if there is some omitted classes, you still have to put in some blank/not-styled classes just for your code maintenance... Very bad idea